# Can my Samsung Galaxy Nexus and iPhone 5 share same micro USB charger?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging

Does the micro USB charger cable that comes with the Samsung Galaxy Nexus be used with the iPhone 5 and vice versa?

Answer (score 6):

Technically yes, but you need a Lightning to micro USB adapter, like [this one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD820ZM/A/lightning-to-micro-usb-adapter).

[image: picture of Apple's official Lightning to micro USB adapter]

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 5 uses a lightning cable.

[image]

Meanwhile, the Galaxy Nexus uses a micro USB cable.

[image]

As you can see, they're quite different.

Answer (score 0):

The USB 2.0 specification define that the USB 2.0 voltage is 5V so if you have the Lightning to micro USB adapter you won`t experience any problems. But directly conecting the micro USB from your Samsung Galaxy Nexus wont work.